# what is the different about access token invalid and expired

Tags: typescript, oauth-2.0

I am handle the access token expired workflow, when the server side return access token expired, I store the client request and refresh the access token using refresh token. But today I found the server side return a litte different. it told me access token invalid. So what is the difference about access token expired and invalid? I did not change the token. is the token expired for a long time changed to invalid automatically? Should I refresh the access token when return invalid?

Comment: There's no general answer to this, but it's totally possible that an OAuth2 server 'forgets' about expired tokens so it doesn't know anymore whether it used to be valid or not. Whether that's the case for you depends on your OAuth2 server and how this was implemented.

Answer (score 2):

The server side should return a generic error with a 401 status code. Something like this, which might even be caused by token revocation. The client should not know the exact cause for the 401. The API should only return a 401 for these reasons and not for other failures.

```json
{   
  "code": "unauthorized",
  "message": "Missing, invalid or expired access token"
}
```

When the client gets a 401 in an API response, it should attempt to refresh the access token, then retry the API request. This should be done once only. If the refresh attempt fails, redirect the user to re-authenticate, after which the client will receive a new set of tokens.